# Asp.Net Identity, como usar apenas Roles ou Claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Voltando ao mesmo assunto: ***ASP.NET Identity*** com ***EntityFramework***.

Independente do tamanho ou planejamento do meu projeto, se eu precisar usar apenas a parte de ***Roles*** ou somente a parte de ***Claims***, isso é possível? E principalmente, como?

Enfim, inibir as propriedades e métodos relacionados a um ou ao outro e não criar as tabelas no banco relacionados ao que foi inutilizado.

Comment: Lá vou eu. Essa vai ser grande.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Respondendo ao cerne da questão, sim. É possível.

## Usando Roles

O projeto padrão ASP.NET MVC5 configurado com ASP.NET Identity não traz uma implementação de provedor de *Role* já configurada, mas isso é bastante simples de configurar:

### Passo 1: Crie um `ApplicationRoleManager`

O `ApplicationRoleManager` é um Singleton que configura o `RoleManager` na sua aplicação. O `RoleManager` é a implementação ASP.NET Identity para o esquema de `Roles`, muito semelhante ao `RoleProvider` do ASP.NET Membership.

Há várias maneiras de fazer isso. A que eu fiz é implementando a classe dentro de `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    }
}
```

(Pretendo melhorar essa implementação algum dia, mas serve para a resposta por enquanto).

### Passo 2: Criar um CRUD para `Roles`

#### Controllers/RolesController.cs

```
namespace SeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public class RolesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private readonly ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

        // GET: Roles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            return View(roles);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(IdentityRole role)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(role);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
        {
            var role = _roleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id.ToString());
            return View(role);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(IdentityRole role)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                await _roleManager.UpdateAsync(role);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(role);
        }

        // GET: Roles/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var role = _roleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id.ToString());
            if (role == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(role);
        }

        // POST: Roles/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id.ToString());
            _roleManager.Delete(role);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Views/Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Users</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var role in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@role.Id</td>
                <td>@role.Name</td>
                <td>
                    @role.Users.Count
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Views/Create.cshtml

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

#### Views/Edit.cshtml

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
}
```

#### Views/Delete.cshtml

```
@model Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Color</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Para inserir um usuário numa *Role*:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var currentUser = userManager.FindByName(User.Identity.GetUserName());

var roleresult = userManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "Nome da Role");
```

Para verificar se um usuário está numa *Role*, o comando é o mesmo do ASP.NET Membership:

```
if (User.IsInRole("Padrão")) { ... }
```

O comando pode ser usado no Razor, em qualquer *View*

## Usando Claims

Não sei se vale a pena descrever todo o processo porque `Claims` se baseia no conceito de políticas de validação. Seria necessário definir uma política de validação antes para eu poder esboçar uma resposta (e que, consequentemente, mereceria uma pergunta em separado).

Em todo caso, [aqui há um exemplo de implementação de Claims usando como política o CEP do endereço do usuário](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185907.aspx).

### Adendo: Por que não é possível alterar a estrutura das tabelas

Dentro de `Models\IdentityModels.cs` do seu projeto, temos a seguinte classe:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> { ... }
```

[`IdentityDbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identitydbcontext(v=vs.108).aspx) possui no seu código fonte a seguinte implementação:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Maps table names, and sets up relationships between the various user entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }

        // Needed to ensure subclasses share the same table
        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        user.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
        user.Property(u => u.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") {IsUnique = true}));

        // CONSIDER: u.Email is Required if set on options?
        user.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TUserRole>()
            .HasKey(r => new {r.UserId, r.RoleId})
            .ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TUserLogin>()
            .HasKey(l => new {l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId})
            .ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

        modelBuilder.Entity<TUserClaim>()
            .ToTable("AspNetUserClaims");

        var role = modelBuilder.Entity<TRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        role.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") {IsUnique = true}));
        role.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
    }
```

Para evitar a construção dessas tabelas, você teria que reescrever `IdentityDbContext`, deixando de utilizar o que já é padrão. Não que seja impossível, mas que para isso você teria que reimplementar o pacote todo, o que não acho razoável pra um efeito desejado tão pequeno.

Comment: Eu ia fazer a autenticação via Claims, mas como tenho muitos itens, fiz um teste com 300claims, ele se perdia e não carregava em memória :\, optei por role mesmo

Comment: Eu avancei um pouco mais nessa resposta, mas preciso de mais tempo ainda. Tá complicado meu dia-a-dia aqui.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Claro! http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-beta1-140128/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework