# Como criar um login com diferentes níveis de permissão?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, login

Como criar um login com diferentes níveis de permissão? É necessário criar uma tabela no banco de dados para realizar login? Tenho lido sobre formsauthentication, cookies e etc, mas ainda não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Primeiro é preciso delimitar a tecnologia. Eu já respondi aqui no SO várias perguntas sobre métodos de autenticação, a saber: ASP.NET Identity, ASP.NET Membership e Forms Authentication. Sobre qual você gostaria de saber?

Comment: Acho que o Membership parece ser o mais simples para se começar. Tô meio perdido no meio dessas tantas possibilidades de realizar login e etc. Se não for muito trabalhoso, você poderia explicar os 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou explicar dois: **ASP.NET Membership** e **ASP.NET Identity**.

## ASP.NET Membership

É uma arquitetura padrão de dados feita para lidar com os usuários de uma aplicação. No caso supõe-se que sua aplicação possuirá a própria base de usuários, e alguns outros sistemas de logins de outros sites podem ser integrados. Pode trabalhar com o Forms Authentication, que é outro padrão da Microsoft, muito mais simples, mas dirigido ao processo de autenticação do usuário em si.

Existe uma implementação (muito) simples de logins e senhas chamada **Simple Membership** em que não é necessário escrever código. [Aqui tem um tutorial de como fazer](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-simplemembership-in-asp.net-mvc-4.htm).

Caso você queira implementar algo mais customizado, tem algumas respostas minhas em que ensino em detalhes como fazer:

- [Tela de login com membership e mvc5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27738/tela-de-login-com-membership-e-mvc5)
- [Segurança e autorização usando Roles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25567/seguran%C3%A7a-e-autoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-usando-roles/25586#25586)
- [Como criar uma página de login e senha no ASP.NET?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21608/pagina-de-login-e-senha/21609#21609)

## ASP.NET Identity

Sendo o Membership limitado para trabalhar com novos métodos de autenticação e permissão, foi criado o Identity, que basicamente traz agumas novidades como trabalhar com Claims e métodos mais sofisticados de identificação de usuários.

Algumas respostas minhas a respeito:

- [Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220)
- [Asp.Net Identity, como usar apenas Roles ou Claims?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32511/asp-net-identity-como-usar-apenas-roles-ou-claims/32643#32643)

Comment: Obrigado! Acho que o membership consegue suprir minhas necessidades. Só uma duvida. É necessária uma tabela para guardar as roles? ou basta adicionar esse campo na tabela usuario, por exemplo?

Comment: Melhor deixar em uma tabela em separado, e você associar quais usuários pertencem a quais roles.

Comment: Entendi. Vou implementar aqui, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Uma ultima duvida. Eu fiz uma tabela com os campos idrole(primary key), namerole e idusuario(chave estrangeira) Essa tabela é o suficiente? Ou você acha que eu devo adicionar alguma outra coisa?

Comment: @RyanSantos Não use `UsuarioId` na definição da Role. Uma Role pode conter vários usuários. Não é uma Role por Usuário.

Comment: Percebi isso na hora que postei! Haha vou corrigir. Mas vc acha que essa table é o suficiente?

Comment: Não sei. Normalmente eu coloco só Id e Nome mesmo.