# Como realizar permissões de acesso via AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou pesquisando como implementar um controle de acesso em minha aplicação Web.

Estou utilizando Asp.Net MVC com identity, a ideá é que determinado usuário só possa acessar determinada pagina.

Então, em pesquisa verifiquei que podemos utilizar `AuthorizeAttribute`, primeiro podemos definir somente como `[Authorize]`, onde somente usuarios autenticados poderão acessar o método em questão.

Também, verifiquei que podemos utilizar `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]` onde somente usuários que satisfazem essa condição iram poder acessar o método em questão.

Porém, como defino essas `Roles`? em pesquisa pelo StackOverFlow, encontrei uma resposta sobre: [Asp.Net Identity, como usar apenas Roles ou Claims?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32511/asp-net-identity-como-usar-apenas-roles-ou-claims/32643#32643), que já me esclareceu algumas duvidas.

Também, em pesquisa na internet, achei algumas pessoas falando que tem que configurar no `web.config`, ref: [Managing Authorization Using ASP.NET Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Então isso me gerou uma confusão:

- Qual modelo está correto?
- Tem vantagens, ou desvantagens entre um ou outro?
- Qual modelo utiliza as tabelas do `identity` ou seja, o SQL Server?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]